# What specifications does a router need to run well while acting as an OpenVPN server via dd-wrt?

Tags: router

I need a router for under, say, £50 which is capable of running dd-wrt's OpenVPN server, and still run well.

This is a home router with 2 or 3 devices connected to it at a time, nothing fancy.

I live in the UK. Tried to get an anwer out of dd-wrt forum but no luck yet.

Comment: Do you want purpose-built router hardware, or would a do-it-yourself like a Raspberry Pi work?

Comment: Well I'd prefer a normal router, but what raspbomagic do you have in mind?

Comment: A Pi 3 with an additional USB network adapter should be plenty fast enough, but it's definitely a case of "some assembly required".

Comment: The poor USB performance of a PI would be quite a bottleneck on any fibre connection.